# Ошибка запуска exe файла Python с помощью планировщика задач

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, windows-10, scheduler

Написал скрипт на Python (в телеграме пару сообщений пишет человеку). Сделал его exe файлом (pyinstaller'ом). Добавил в планировщик задач, чтобы он запускался каждый день, но происходит ошибка 0х1. Как ее исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможные варианты: проверить, от имени какого пользователя запускается программа. при запуске отимени системы у неё другой path - может не видеть чего то. Проверить, в каком каталоге происходит запуск программы. И наконец, проверить - может, прошрамма уже есть в памяти, и они конфликтуют за ресурсы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта как я решил проблему (сейчас я уже не помню какой именно): во-первых, нужно указать рабочий файл в Планировщике задач, если программа использует дополнительные файлы (txt например), во-вторых, нужно точно проверить работает ли программа вне Планировщика задач, нет ли ошибок.

Еще стоит обратить внимание на слова S.H.

> Возможные варианты: проверить, от имени какого пользователя запускается программа. при запуске отимени системы у неё другой path - может не видеть чего то. Проверить, в каком каталоге происходит запуск программы. И наконец, проверить - может, прошрамма уже есть в памяти, и они конфликтуют за ресурсы?